# step by step tutorial for newbie

Tags: r, time-series, machine-learning, forecasting, references

I'm looking to join the field of statistics and more exactly to forecasting. I'm a software developer and I just started playing with R.

Can you recommend me some tutorials related to forecasting, but something which beginners can handle. It will be great also to read and try some forecasting related problems in which the input data needs some cleaning.

Answer (score 4):

I find this online text by Rob Hyndman very helpful. The material is very nicely presented with examples.

[Forecasting Principles by Rob Hyndman and George Athana­sopou­los](https://www.otexts.org/book/fpp)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest

[Hyndman and Athanasopoulos
Forecasting: principles and practice](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/)

it is good and free.

Comment: I think this suggestion was already covered by Zeron's answer some hours earlier. The only piece of additional information ('it is free') would be better as a comment on that answer.